# Keras shape not working

Tags: python, keras

I have been trying to make a auto encoder and i have been having some issues. So i am loading a 32x32 grayscale image into the network and it keeps giving me this error.

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
(32, 32, 1)
253.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 32, in <module>
    model.fit(out,out, batch_size=16, epochs=10)
  File "C:\Users\nathanmoosh\Anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages\keras\models.py", line 965, in fit
    validation_steps=validation_steps)
  File "C:\Users\nathanmoosh\Anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1593, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "C:\Users\nathanmoosh\Anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1426, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='input')
  File "C:\Users\nathanmoosh\Anaconda3_2\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 110, in _standardize_input_data
    'with shape ' + str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (32, 32, 1)
```

And this is my code.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation,Dropout,Flatten
from keras.preprocessing import image
import numpy
img = image.load_img("imgs/test3.jpg", target_size=(32, 32), grayscale = True)

x = image.img_to_array(img)
out = numpy.array(x)

print(out.shape)
print(out[0][0][0])

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(1025, activation='relu', input_shape=(32,32,3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, activation='relu'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(out,out, batch_size=16, epochs=10)
```

Please help!

Comment: Not sure if this helps, however, your image's shape is (32, 32, 1) while you're expecting shape (32, 32, 3) on your first layer.

Comment: Your training data should have shape (num_samples, 32, 32, 3)

Comment: I changed it and it did nothing.

Comment: You should do this instead `out = numpy.array([x])`. And your image should be of dimension (32,32,3) not (32,32,1).

Answer (score 0):

As @MatiasValdenegro suggested, the shape of the input should be (num_samples, 32, 32, 3). In your case, it is (1, 32, 32, 3), not (32, 32, 3).

To do so, after `out = numpy.array(x)`, add this line:

```
out = out[numpy.newaxis, :, :, :] # (1, 32, 32, 3)
```